# Init field with setter and getter

Tags: apex, getter

I can write `Integer var {get; set;}`

but can not `Integer var {get; set;} = 0`

or

`Integer var = 0 {get; set;}`

Is it impossible to init field with set-get at the same line?

Comment: What do u think `set` use for? You can initialize them in the constructor as well.

Comment: @Mr.Frodo but I need to write second line to init this `set`?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_methods.htm it might help you on understanding the getter and setter

Comment: `Integer var{get; set{  var=0; } }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set them in single line as well. You just need to follow the format. Which is

```
public class BasicProperty {
   public integer prop {
      get { return prop; }
      set { prop = value; }
   }
}
```

if you want to set a single element then can do this

```
public class BasicProperty {
       public integer prop {
          get ;
          set { prop = value; }
       }
    }
```

You can also make them public or private

```
public integer Z { get; protected set; }
```

So there is no such limitation that you can't use them in single line.

[Apex properties](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm)

Comment: You provided 3 examples, and none of them initialized property, which is what author asked about